# Trying to use post-message, but control id keeps changing

Tags: autohotkey, postmessage

I'm trying to send the command to restore mediaportal to fullscreen when it has been minimized to the system tray.

I identified the window for right clicking on the system tray icon as
007E02C0:(WindowsForms10.Window.0.app.0.2386859)

To Restore mediaportal I right click on the systram icon and click Restore

Then it sends this command four times
WM_COMMAND
  Code: 0
  Control ID: 290
  Control HWND: 0x00000000

The problem is that every I click restore, the Control ID changes.  Each time I do this the control ID is incremented by 2.  What do I do?

Comment: I gave up, and instead did an image search to find the system tray icons co-ordinates then sent a double click to that location.  

    CoordMode, pixel, screen
CoordMode, mouse, screen
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 1500,980, 1920, 1200, C:\mp_tray.bmp
if ErrorLevel = 0
  {
  FoundX += 5
  FoundY +=5
  MouseMove, FoundX, FoundY
  Sleep 500
  Click, 2
  }

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try stetting DetectHiddenWindows to on and using AutoHotkey to unhide the window directly.